# How to write condition if the column is not null in mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement

[image]

I need to eliminate the rows, if the enrollDate and cancelDate is same. So i wrote the query as follows
 `SELECT a.id, a.clientId, a.enrollDate, a.cancelDate FROM gap_borrower a WHERE STR_TO_DATE( a.`loanEndDate`,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) >= STR_TO_DATE(  '2015-12-31',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AND FIND_IN_SET( a.status,  'A,C' ) AND STR_TO_DATE( a.`enrollDate`,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) <> STR_TO_DATE( a.`cancelDate`,  '%Y-%m-%d' )`

But if cancelDate is Null, it didn't display as different.(Only need to eliminate the id=8551 in the above figure. This is my problem)  So i wrote another query using if condition

```
SELECT a.id, a.clientId, a.enrollDate, a.cancelDate FROM gap_borrower a WHERE STR_TO_DATE( a.`loanEndDate` ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) >= STR_TO_DATE(  '2015-12-31',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AND FIND_IN_SET( a.status,  'A,C' ) AND (CASE WHEN a.cancelDate IS NOT NULL THEN (STR_TO_DATE( a.`enrollDate` ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) <> STR_TO_DATE(  a.cancelDAte,  '%Y-%m-%d' )) END  )
```

Its also fails.Please guide me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.clientId, a.enrollDate, a.cancelDate 
FROM gap_borrower a WHERE 
    DATE(a.loanEndDate) >= DATE('2015-12-31') 
    AND FIND_IN_SET( a.status,  'A,C' ) 
    AND (DATE(a.enrollDate) <> DATE(a.cancelDate) OR a.enrollDate IS NULL OR a.cancelDate IS NULL)
    --uncomment this if you don't need rows where  the both dates are null
    --AND (a.enrollDate IS NOT NULL or a.cancelDate IS NOT NULL)
```